# node.js turning string into file to be uploaded to webserver

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, file-upload, ftp

Let's say I have a string that is dynamically created using defined variables. For example:

```
<html>
   <head>
   .... blah blah blah ....
   </head>

   <body>

    <h1>Clan Name</h1>

  </body>

</html>
```

The string would be stored as "htmlOutput" and then I need to upload that string to a directory on a web-server using a variable as the file-name. For example the file-name might be 495731951.html

How is this achieved?

I've had a look at jsftp but there's nothing for uploading the strings value. I don't want to have to create a new file on the local machine for each file as there will be a lot of files.

Thank you!

Comment: You can always create local files, then delete them as you're done with them.

Answer (score -3):

I assume that you have an access to that remote server. Instead of using FTP I'll suggest to write a simple PHP script that handles POST requests and saves a file.

```
// save.php
$html = isset($_POST['content']) ? $_POST['content'] : '';
if($html !== '') {
  $file = 'file.txt';
  file_put_contents($file, $content);
}
```

I'm suggesting PHP because I guess that it is supported there. I again, assume that there is no Node.js on that server.

Once you have such file there (`save.php`) you may send your variable with the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module.

```
request.post('http://service.com/save.php', {
  form: {
    content: htmlOutput
  }
});
```

Comment: You assume too much for this to be a valid answer. Get the facts, then answer!

Comment: does it need somthing else to check whether there is already a file with that name made>

Comment: Well, Shivam Paw, I guess yes. You probably need a check if the file exists.